# How to multiply a numpy float array from an Excel sheet by a constant?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm reading the values from an Excel file using the `xlrd` package and storing them into an array. I printed the array and it got the values from the Excel. Now I want to multiply the array by a constant value:

```
def getExcel():    
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(filedialog.askopenfilename())
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(5)
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0)    
    y = []
    ydata = np.array(y, dtype = np.float32)
    x = []
    angle = np.array(x, dtype = np.float32)    
    i=0
    while (i<sheet.nrows):
        if (i%2)>0:            
            angle = np.append(angle, sheet.cell_value(i, 0))            
        else:
            ydata = np.append(ydata, sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
        i+=1
    constant = sheet.cell_value(1, 4)
    rad = np.multiply(angle, 0.0174)    
    print(rad)
```

I expect all of the elements of the `angle` array to be multiplied by `0.0174`, but I'm getting an error as follows:

```
line 27, in getExcel rad = np.multiply(angle, 0.0174)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a 
loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> 
dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: You can multiply a `numpy` array simply like `constant * array`. `np.multiply` expects two arrays, not a float.

Comment: Thank you @ Ardweaden . It worked.